# Where's my arm64 binary?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I'm building an iOS multi-architecture framework. In my build settings, I've added the architectures i386, x86_64, armv7, armv7s, arm64.

It builds successfully.

However, when I run '`lipo -info MyBinaryName`' I'm only seeing the architectures i386, x86_64, armv7, armv7s. ***arm64 is missing***!

Why isn't xcode building for this architecture and how can I resolve?

**arm64 is the architecture for iPhone 5S.*

Comment: Need a little more information. How are you building this framework? Are you using some kind of build script to help with this within Xcode? If so, post the script if you can.

Comment: I'm not using any build script. Why I would need to use a build script if I configure to build all architectures in the build settings.. Shouldn't xcode just make a fat binary from all the architectures in the list? Evidently it is making a fat binary as can be seen from lipo'ing the build product binary, it just seems to be missing that one architecture...

Comment: Not sure if you still need to now, but you used to have to build your framework twice, once for devices and again for the simulator/osx, then combine them which usually involved using a build script. There must be a step or setting somewhere you're missing, but there's no way to know for sure without more information. Does your framework link to another that doesn't support arm64?

Comment: My framework doesn't link to anything else. I don't know much about build scripts -- but it appears that Xcode is building my device & sim binaries just fine without one.. (according to lipo output)